# making a page and getting error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218

Tags: laravel

I am making a signup page and continuously I am getting this

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

when I try to submit data.
what it should do, is to just submit it to the database. but it's not doing it.

welcome blade:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title')
Welcome!!
@endsection
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <form action="{{route('signup')}}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Your E-Mail</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name">
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">                
        </form> 
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Sign In</h2>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Your E-Mail</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>                   
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

User controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\User;
class UserController extends Controller
{
public function postSignUp(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request['email'];
    $name = $request['name'];
    $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

    $user = new User();
    $user -> email = $email;
    $user -> name = $name;
    $user -> password = $password;

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

routes.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
```

});

```
Route::post('/signup',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as' => 'signup'
]);
```

});

Header blade:

```
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-bsexample-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

master blade:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@yield('title')</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

</head>
<body>
@include('includes.header')
<div class="container">
<div>
@yield('content')
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add some code of method

Comment: Do you have a csrf_token?

Comment: Done..@Komal .. please check now.

Comment: no, i don't have it. @neat

Comment: Try this <form action="{{route('signup')}}" method="POST">

Comment: done.. still same error. don't know what to do now. I am unable to find the error.

Comment: Change action action="/signup" and try

Comment: thank you @komal it worked .

Comment: but.. I don't understand. what was the difference? @Komal

Comment: welcome and check my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify route name

```
route('signup')
Route::post('/signup', 'UserController@postSignUp')->name('signup');
```

If your route like this then action should be '/signup' like this

```
Route::post('/signup',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as' => 'signup'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This Exectiption you are facing 
either because you dont have that signup route in routes.php
OR
you are doing post but you have written route::get('signup')

So you need to write route::post there.

Comment: No, both are correct in my code. you can check my code. I edited the answer.

Comment: might be you have same route with get request ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PATCH in your form, you have to add a **method field** helper to spoof the PUT HTTP verb.

Add this in your form or use **post** as the verb in **routes** and **form**.

```
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Comment: where should I add it? in welcome blade after form action?

Answer (score 0):

We have following HTTP methods - get, post, put, patch etc.

When you are trying to insert a record in the database table, we need to use POST method instead of the PATCH method in HTML form.